# Вывод по нажатию

Tags: python

```py
import keyboard

enter = True
for i in text:
    print(i)
    while enter:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('Enter'):
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Пропускает условие `if keyboard.is_pressed` и выводит следующий элемент списка сразу.

Comment: Что такое `keyboard`?

Comment: Библиотека, выше импортировал её, просто забыл добавить сюда

Comment: `enter` с маленькой буквы

Comment: Менял на маленькую, все еще пропускает условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import keyboard

for i in 'text':
    print(i)
    while 1:
        keyboard.wait('enter')
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Плохо изучил библиотеку)